# Получить сообщение из Web App Telegram в чат-боте

Tags: telegram-bot, golang, telegram, web-apps

Помогите, пожалуйста, есть веб приложение из  Web App Telegram в чат-боте, нажимаю кнопку MainButton для передачи сообщения используя метод WebApp.SendData()

```
  Telegram.WebApp.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', function(){
      tg.sendData("some string that we need to send"); 
      //при клике на основную кнопку отправляем данные в строковом виде
   });
```

но не знаю как правильно обработать прилетевшие данные на бэке написанном на Go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    tele "gopkg.in/telebot.v3"
)

func main() {
    pref := tele.Settings{
        Token:  os.Getenv("TOKEN"),
        Poller: &tele.LongPoller{Timeout: 10 * time.Second},
    }

    b, err := tele.NewBot(pref)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    b.Handle("/hello", func(c tele.Context) error {
        return c.Send("Hello!")
    })

    b.Start()
}
```

Получается в этот шаблон кода нужно еще один b.Handle (WebAppData) но не знаю как правильно описать обработку

Читал описание здесь, но мозгов не хватает понять

https://github.com/tucnak/telebot/blob/v3/web_app.go